# Esky, no frozen versions found

Tags: python-2.7, esky

Just following an online tutorial to get a grasp of Esky.
[tutorial here - at correct timestamp](https://youtu.be/vP6j7VDpPrI?t=421)

I can get the "factorial.py" file to run, without Esky - that's basic. Building the exe, in both py2exe and esky form, easy enough.

However, when running the factorial.py (or .exe) with the new Esky lines included, fails, code below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "factorial.py", line 4, in <module>
    app = esky.Esky(sys.executable, "http://localhost:8000")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\esky\__init__.py", line 249, in __init__
    self.reinitialize()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\esky\__init__.py", line 317, in reinitialize
    raise EskyBrokenError("no frozen versions found")
esky.errors.EskyBrokenError: no frozen versions found
```

I've got the Esky .zip file on a localhost HTTP server, as the demo does, and I can navigate to it through a browser.

Note:
I'm on Python2.7
I've written the code, letter for letter, as the lecturer does

All help appreciated

Comment: i am going to assume people down voted because you should have taken relevant parts of the video and posted them here instead of assuming we have time to watch the video

Comment: Noted, I'll get the timestamps shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to try cx freeze, it solved my issues as well. It also has the benefits of being cross platform.

Unfortunately Esky is not being actively developed for almost 5 years now, so it needs some love.

Also check windows firewall / antivirus programs are not blocking the port/program.

Comment: How would you go about the auto updates with can freeze? I've used it before for basic local installation and exe files, but you have to build the app for any changes.

Comment: sorry i don't follow the question

Comment: Cx-freeze locks the application to whatever your source was when you built it. I want to be able to install the application onto a user, and have the application fetch updates automatically. Hence the need for esky

Comment: first sentence of the esky readme, Esky is an auto-update framework for frozen Python applications. Py2exe also freezes the code, Esky is a wrapper for these programs that handles the updating logic.

Comment: I'm fully aware of what Esky does, and how it works. My issue is that Esky cannot find my frozen package

Comment: what exactly do you mean by fails in your original question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81644/discussion-between-arden-and-oliversarfas).

Comment: Have removed p2exe, installed cx-freeze. rerun with a few amendments and all is working.